# Eventemitter angular 4 não funciona

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-eventos

Tenho um Perfil.service que emite um evento para dois componentes que não se comunicam. Ao clicar no link do PerfilComponent, ele dispara o "PerfilService.emitirBeneficios.emit('perfil.beneficiosOpcionais')" e redireciona para o PerfilOpcionaisComponent. Porém, nao aparece o conteudo no console.log. Entretanto, se eu voltar e fizer novamente, ele emite.

//PerfilService

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private config: AppConfig,  private http: HttpClient, private router: Router ){ }

static emitirBeneficios = new EventEmitter();
```

//PerfilComponent

```
redirect(perfil: Perfil) {
    PerfilService.emitirBeneficios.emit(perfil.beneficiosOpcionais)
    this.router.navigate(['/perfil/opcionais']);
```

//PerfilOpcionaisComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
    PerfilService.emitirBeneficios.subscribe(beneficiosOpcionais => 
    console.log(beneficiosOpcionais));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) em um serviço é considerado uma [prática ruim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter). Basicamente, `EventEmitter` é uma abstração do *framework* Angular e o seu único propósito é emitir eventos em componentes.

Angular nunca nos garantirá que `EventEmitter` continuará a ser um `Observable`. Isso significa que é necessário refatorar o código se ele mudar. A única API que deve ser acessada é o método `emit()`, sendo que você nunca deve realizar o *subscribe* manualmente. Adicionalmente, o correto é usar `EventEmitter` somente para *event binding* entre um componente pai e um componente filho.

Neste seu caso, eu recomendo a utilização do [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) ou do [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#replaysubject).

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia

```
@Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

O eventEmitter precisa ser um Output já que ele vai enviar uma resposta e precisa ser importado como

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Porém a pratica do EventEmitter é para a comunicação entre components pelo HTML, onde você precisa gerar um selector com @Input() para executar um procedimento onde ele vai retornar com um @Output() atravéz do EventEmitter para o elemento Pai (emitter) = "nomedometodo(valor)".